# MySQL Query Failed in PHP but Success through MYSQL Client

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone, please take a look at my code in PHP, why is it failed.

**CODE**

```
$mysqli->query('LOCK TABLES fg_out_body READ,fg_out_head READ');
$sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM fg_out_body WHERE part_no='$partno' AND lot_no='$lotno'";
$resultCheck = $mysqli->query($sqlCheck);
if ($resultCheck->num_rows > 0) {
  echo 'record exists';
} else {
    $sqlHead = "INSERT IGNORE INTO fg_out_head(fg_doc_no,`type`,`date`,acc_no,
                                           prod_loc,destination,user_id) 
                                    VALUES('$docno','$tipe','$tanggal','$customer',
                                           '$prodloc','$destination','$userid')";
    if ($mysqli->query($sqlHead)) {
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }
}
```

But if i paste the query directly to mysql, it can run without error.

CODE

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO 
 fg_out_head(fg_doc_no,`type`,`date`,acc_no,prod_loc,destination,user_id) 
VALUES('FVOT-00001','VARIANCE OUT','2016-04-27','','','Other','')
```

This message from the console

`Table 'fg_out_head' was locked with a READ lock and can't be updated`

Comment: echo your query and paste it here also post your connection code!!

Comment: Use `if (!$mysqli->query("YOUR_QUERY")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}` to check error

Comment: Are u sure you are having connection? Try another simple query to see if it is your connection or the query

Comment: @Laurens Just output the error message like Saty suggests that will tell you everything you need to know

Comment: okay, i know where is the problem, due to the table lock that i set before this query. i will update the questions, kindly help me.

Comment: Of course you are not running the same query in the mysql client. You are hard coding the parameters when you run in the mysql client and in PHP you are using parameter which may or may not be set, and which may or may not be the correct data type or length etc etc

Comment: You should really look into prepared statements...

Comment: Why do you feel you need to use the `IGNORE` in that query??? That suggests that you already knwo this query is dodgy

Comment: @RiggsFolly to prevent MySQL throw an exception for the duplicate entry.

Comment: You should check the manual: `The session that holds the lock can read the table (but not write it).` So yes, when you read-lock it for your current session, your current session cannot write anything.

Comment: i am trying to get full control of the table for current session while letting other to READ the table as well. setting to WRITE will lock the table from other to accessing the table, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the [MYSQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html)

> Rules for Lock Acquisition
>
> To acquire table locks within the current session, use the LOCK TABLES statement. The following lock types are available:
>
> READ [LOCAL] lock:
>
> The session that holds the lock can read the table (but not write it).

So try setting a WRITE lock instead then you will be allowed to write to the locked table from this session

Comment: so if setting a WRITE lock will lock the table from other user as well, they cant even read the table? is it right? I am trying to get the full access of the table while other can read but cant write.

Comment: Yes, read the page that I linked to, its all in there, oddly enough

Comment: The read lock would have allowed other sessions to INSERT rows, thus negating the point of your checking the row already existsed, as it would have been possible for some other session to have created the row toy checked for aftre your checking and before you inserted

Comment: is there any way to achieve what i want. full control of table for current session while letting other to read the table as well.

Comment: Exactly what situation are you trying to stop happening by setting these locks?

Comment: As long as you remember to UNLOCK the tables as soon as you have checked existance and Inserted, the lock should remain for only a few milli seconds

Comment: But if you believe the LOCK is necessary in this situation, then thats what you have to do

Comment: okay, i am going to insert a part and qty record into the outgoing table so i am gonna to stop other session to insert the same part into the outgoing table, i am afraid that the stock balance will become negative if other session is completed before this current session.

Comment: Is this a MYISAM or INNODB table(s)